# Shell.Current.GoToAsync() doesn't work as expected

Tags: c#, maui

I registered the route and called the method after clicking on the button, but the transition to the desired page does not work. I'm a beginner and I don't really understand what the problem is.

Route registration:

```cs
namespace MuseumFinder;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));

        Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPage/MuseumListPage", typeof(MuseumListPage));
    }
}
```

Method call:

```cs
namespace MuseumFinder;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();        
    }

    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {        
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("//MainPage/MuseumListPage");        
    }
}
```

After clicking on the button, the following happens:

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MuseumFinder.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MuseumFinder.Views"
    xmlns:searchHandlers="clr-namespace:MuseumFinder.SearchHandlers"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MuseumFinder"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">

    <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />

</Shell>
```

Comment: Could you please add the appshell.xaml page?

Comment: What's your intended page structure? Why don't you just skip the "MainPage" part of the route that leads to the `MuseumListPage`?

Comment: I have pages for administrators and for users. And the mainpage contains 2 buttons to open these pages

Answer (score 1):

This here:

```
 <ShellContent
        Title="Home"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}"
        Route="MainPage" />
```

Combined with this:

```
Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MainPage), typeof(MainPage));
```

Is a mistake.
Do not define your routes twice.
Once in XAML, and once in XAML.CS.

```
Routing.RegisterRoute("MainPage/MuseumListPage", typeof(MuseumListPage));
```

This here is a mistake. In 99.99% of the cases you will not want to do this.
**nameof(MuseumListPage)** is the correct (usual) route.

It is good idea to share your App builder.

Also "does not work" is very bad way to describe things.
If everything worked fine, you would not be here. So details matter.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the duplicate registration of `MainPage` in your *AppShell.xaml.cs*, because that's already defined as a `<ShellContent>` in your *AppShell.xaml* file.

You also do not need to provide the root element in your routes. In your case, the `MainPage` will be on the root level. Therefore, you can register `MuseumListPage` simply like below:

```cs
namespace MuseumFinder;

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(MuseumListPage), typeof(MuseumListPage));
    }
}
```

You can then navigate to the `MuseumListPage` route like this in your event handler:

```cs
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MuseumListPage));        
}
```